# Add column with variable column name to dataframes in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames.

```
l <- list("a"=data.frame(a=1:2,b=1:2),"b"=data.frame(a=1:2,b=1:2))
l
$a
a b
1 1 1
2 2 2

$b
a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

I am trying to add a column to each of those data.frames. The name of the column is defined in a variable.

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
j=1
lapply(l,function(x) x[[paste0("Column",LETTERS[j])]] <- 0)
```

I have split up the above to be more readable. But this doesn't work either.

```
cname <- paste0("Column",LETTERS[j])
fun1 <- function(x,y) x[[y]] <- 0
lapply(l,fun1,cname)
```

The `cbind` approach works with `lapply()`, but I am not quite sure how to add a column name through variable. This also shows the output I am looking for.

```
lapply(l,function(x) cbind(x,ColumnA=0))

$a
  a b ColumnA
1 1 1       0
2 2 2       0

$b
  a b ColumnA
1 1 1       0
2 2 2       0
```

Perhaps someone has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to assign on the `lhs` would be with `:=` and evaluate (`!!`) the string in `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
j <- 1
map(l, ~ .x %>% 
           mutate(!! str_c("Column",LETTERS[j]) := 0))
#$a
#  a b ColumnA
#1 1 1       0
#2 2 2       0

#$b
#  a b ColumnA
#1 1 1       0
#2 2 2       0
```

---

Or in `base R`, modify the `fun1` to return the dataset after the assignment

```
fun1 <- function(x,y) {x[[y]] <- 0; x}
cname <-  paste0("Column",LETTERS[j])
lapply(l, fun1, y = cname)
#$a
#  a b ColumnA
#1 1 1       0
#2 2 2       0

#$b
#  a b ColumnA
#1 1 1       0
#2 2 2       0
```

Comment: Hmm.. I forgot to mention, but I am looking for a solution without external libraries.

Comment: I forgot to return x in the function which was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr`...

```r
llply(l,function(x) data.frame(x,c=0))
$a
  a b c
1 1 1 0
2 2 2 0

$b
  a b c
1 1 1 0
2 2 2 0
```

Comment: plyr has been deprecated in favor of dplyr for a while now FYI

Comment: How would you do it in `dplyr` then (minus `purrr`)?

Comment: I suppose I misspoke: it's been deprecated in favor of mostly dplyr, plus purrr for list-focused tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `replace` to each component of `l` with the indicated arguments.

```
lapply(l, replace, paste0("Column", LETTERS[j]), 0)
```

giving:

```
$a
  a b ColumnA
1 1 1       0
2 2 2       0

$b
  a b ColumnA
1 1 1       0
2 2 2       0
```

### Update

Revised.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transform` and use `setNames` to change column name

```
lapply(l, function(x) setNames(transform(x, temp = 0), c(names(x), cname)))

#$a
#  a b ColumnA
#1 1 1       0
#2 2 2       0

#$b
#  a b ColumnA
#1 1 1       0
#2 2 2       0
```

Or also change only the last column name

```
lapply(l, function(x) {transform(x, temp = 0);names(x)[ncol(x)] <- cname;x})
```